# Set Variable Path in Pycharm or export interpreter

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to set a variable path in pycharm like Idea ?

My goal is to be able to use this variable in the Paths tab of a python interpreter. As it is now, I have to enter custom paths specific to my machine any time I want to setup this interpreter on a new machine.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interpreter is referenced by its name in the project file (`.idea/misc.xml`). The actual elements of the `Paths` are not stored in the project, but inside the user specific PyCharm [configuration directory](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) (`~/.PyCharm20/config/options/jdk.table.xml`).

Path Variables feature affects only project files, so it will not help here. You still have to define the interpreter Paths again on each machine as it's system IDE configuration, not project.

Comment: Isn't there a way to overcome it? It is really annoying. There exists related [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-2856#tab=Comments), but no solution.